# Bayesian Sets and Finding the Top Sets

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian

Bayesian Sets proposed by Ghahramani and Heller (http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/bsets-nips05.pdf) provides a useful way to find sets of items based upon a query (eg dog would return cat, pet) and produces comparable output to google sets. I was wondering how the method could be used to find the top sets without first providing a word (item) as a query. Is anybody aware of active learning on Bayesian sets where the sets with the highest density are identified?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Bayesian Sets return a sat of items related to the query. If you have no query, nothing is related. What would be "top sets"?

Comment: Let me explain why I need a list of the top (or prominent) sets that are in a dataset. I don't want the user to specify a query, rather I would like to present to the user a list of sets that are found within a dataset. I would like to rank these sets.

Answer (score 0):

Bayesian Sets essentially performs feature selection (see: A Simple Bayesian Framework for Content-Based Image Retrieval) to rank items in a set. And the weights of features are decided via seed examples of this set. Without seeds there is no way to accomplish this. So it boils down to finding "sets of seeds".

To do so, you can find "clusters" in the data (say using K-means) and supply their "centroids" (or data points which represents a clusters) as sets of seeds. Basically, what now you will be doing is ranking the items in each cluster (which you could call as topsets).